# from 2 points and an angle get position of tird

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

Ive got 2 points and an angle and want to find where the 3rd point is. A drawing:
[image]

I know a, p1, p2 and the distance d between them. Now I want to find the coordinates of p3.
For example: a = 30°; p1 = (10,10,10); p2 = (10,10,20); p3 = (?,10,?)
Note: The y-value stays the same, because of how the axes are named.
How would I do that?

Comment: You need more data. Knowing `a,p1,p2` will tell the straight `p1->p3` but not the point p3. For it, you need also for example the distance p1-p3 or p2-p3.

Comment: the distance between p3 and p1 is equal to the distance between p1 and p2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given points `P1` and `P2` we calculate the distance between them:

```
d12 = sqrt((P2.x - P1.x)*(P2.x - P1.x) + (P2.y - P1.y)*(P2.y - P1.y) + (P2.z - P1.z)*(P2.z - P1.z))
```

Notice you can also use `math.pow(P2.x-P1.x, 2)` instead of re-multiplying

We also calculate the angle P1 to P2, knowing that the `.y` coordinates are the same:

```
aP1P2 = math.atan2(P2.z-P1.z, P2.x-P1.x)  # In radians, not degrees
```

Now we substract the given `a` angle:

```
aP1P3 = aP1P2 - math.radians(a)  # 'a' is given in degrees, but we use radians
```

Finally the point P3 is given by P1, the distance, and the calculated angle:

```
P3.x = P1.x + d12 * math.cos(aP1P3)
P3.y = P1.y # same as P1 an P2
P3.z = P1.z + d12 * math.sin(aP1P3)
```